# Rename multiple files in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have some files in my folder like:

```
asd55.png
qwe55.png
zxc55.png
```

I want to remove the 55 and get the result:

```
asd.png
qwe.png
zxc.png
```

I tried with:

```
ren *55.png *.png
```

but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Test this on a folder of test files.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.png) do ren "%%a" "???%%~xa"
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `ren *.png ???.png`. But `ren ???55.png ???.png` is safer. I already answered this exact same question at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/q/805733/109090) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this finally looking the [example](https://superuser.com/questions/720502/batch-renaming-automation-2-to) and applied to my case:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%G in (*55.*) do (
set new=%%~nG
set new=!new:~0,-2!
ren "%%~G" "!new!%%~xG"
)
```